# Taking power with loop(with-out pow() function)

Tags: c, loops, integer, long-integer, exponent

Im trying the powers of an integer. For example if my integers is 2 first 10 power is 2^1,2^2...2^10. Im using

```
while (expnt < 10)
{
    preExpnt = expnt;
    while (preExpnt)
    {
        preExpnt *= num;
        printf("%lld\n", preExpnt);
    }
    expnt++;

}
```

but it doesn't work.`

Comment: The inner `while` loop serves no useful purpose.

Comment: should i use for?

Comment: You should remove the inner `while` and just keep the two lines that are the body of that `while`.

Comment: ok i will try it now

Comment: it works but its taking power its multiply.

Comment: So now I need to refer you to the [help], especially the part about [mcve]. Which means posting a complete set of code, that others can compile and run, as well as showing the expected output, and the actual output from the program.

Comment: "It does not work" may be factually 100% correct, but you can also add *how* it does not work. It may help us help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a way you could achieve your purpose.

```
int num = 2; // for example
int out = 1;
for (int exp = 1; exp <= 10; exp++)
{
    out *= num;
    printf("%d\n", out);
}
```

Remarks about your code:

- Your inner while loop is infinite if `num` and `expnt` are both different from 0.
- Assigning `preExpnt` to the value of `expnt` at each step and multiplying by `num` would display a something like: `1*n 2*n 3*n 4*n ...` if `expnt` starts at 1.

Comment: the problem is this code is 2^2= 4 thats ok but than its thakes 4^2=16 and than 16^2. they not powers of 2

Comment: what?, 16 is not a power of two??, neither 256?... look, maybe Alamit's code was doing this (skipping 8, then 32, 64 and 128), before he edited it, but these are definitely powers of 2, I think everyone who use C should get to know them very well, this numbers represent a lot of crucial things, the bit-length of types that translate transparently to machine words (BYTE (8), WORD (16), DWORD (32), QWORD (64)...), ranges of values they can store (- 1). Really helpful with things like alignment and padding, to name a few. So don't get them wrong, some C zealots might want to lynch you for it. <:0

Comment: * `conspicuously hiding my pitchfork behind my back` *